# Android 12 breaks AIDL/IPC with runtime permissions on IPC APK

Tags: android, android-service, android-bluetooth, aidl

Pre-Android 12 I could create proprietary Bluetooth health device driver service APKs and exchange info with them from a main application via AIDL. The driver APKs have no UI and launch nothing when installed. Though these APKs used Bluetooth and BLE all runtime permissions could be given from the primary application. These APKs could be installed and uninstalled without changing any code in the primary application (no action from the user, either).

With Android 12, that is no longer true. These service APKs are useless without the primary application yet Android 12 is requiring runtime permissions from these UI-less and launch-less services.

Does anyone know how to work around this issue or why Android even did this? Defeats the entire purpose of creating plugin drivers! Is there a way to give the permissions from the primary application to the installed driver? The driver does not crash due to no runtime bluetooth permissions until the application tries to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've faced similar problem also on pre-12. My apk-lib-plugin-aidl app needed some other perms and I've ended with one and only `Activity` (not set as launcher!) with transparent, or just black, background, which was just running runtime perm dialogs in `onResume`. didn't even care about result, besides `finish()`ing `Activity`. I've also added two methods for AIDL checking perms and running this `Activity`

```
    override fun openGrantPermissionsActivity() {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "openGrantPermissionsActivity")
        val intent = Intent(this@AidlService, PermissionActivity::class.java)
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    override fun checkPermissions(): Boolean {
        val permissionsOk = Utils.checkPermission(
            this@AidlService, PermissionActivity.RECORD_AUDIO_PERM
        )
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "checkPermissions are ok:$permissionsOk")
        return permissionsOk
    }
```

would be great to "share" any permission granted to "my app" with other apps, but afaik thats not possible

Comment: So let me get this straight - you were forced into making a UI component in your 'background' apk. Not sure how you engage the AIDL methods. My plugin APK is a service and it is a service in my 'primary' app that monitors the installation of these driver plugins. Do you ask for these permissions from your 'calling' app or your plugin?

Comment: my apk-lib is also a `Service`, which run mostly native code. no related Activities at all. but I needed microphone perm and only for this one runtime-only-afaik perm I've made transparent/black `Activity` which runs perm dialog. in AIDL I have `void openGrantPermissionsActivity();` and `boolean checkPermissions();`. inside `Stub` these are overriden and implemented, on `Service`-plugin side. added code to answer

Comment: You got it man!!! Thanks a heap.  When the apk is installed I check for the permission and if not granted I start an activity that has only an 'onResume()' and ask for the permission.  Had some issues starting the activity from the service but that was another issue.  I give you 600 kudos for the work around. Everything is contained within the installed APK - no new AIDL methods needed so far.

Comment: maybe some day there will be an option for sharing permissions, at least between apps signed with same key, but afaik not possible in any way for now. we have to stick to some basic GUI on plugin-side. so... you're welcome, good luck :)